# Flexbox doesn't recalculate styles

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, safari, flexbox

In Chrome and Safari width of the `div` is calculated only once.
Any changes of dom tree, adding or removing classes and resizes of the window are ignored.
How can I force width recalculation without page reload?

https://jsfiddle.net/7xpoccg6/7/
Resize demo area vertically there, then click <kbd>Run</kbd> to reload example in new size.
Or use full page switch in the snippet.

```css
html, body, section {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

section {
  display: flex;
}

section:before, section::after {
  content: "";
  flex: 1 0 0px;
  background: antiquewhite;
  height: 100%;
}

div {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  height: 50%;
  background: green;
  align-self: flex-end;
}

svg {
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="c">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 1000 2000" class="avatar">
      <ellipse cx="500" cy="1000" rx="500" ry="1000" fill="red" />
    </svg>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: looks like bugging too in my FF (width not updated , svg hidden partially) ... you may inbricate flex boxes , but for webkit i guess you'll need to force a reflow on resize . (ex in the fiddle with hover and position ) : https://jsfiddle.net/7xpoccg6/10/

Comment: @GCyrillus, in my FF it is updated fine, but very slow - with visible lags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as commented, you may inbricate flexbox and force a reflow at screen to awaken webkit:

*example with `vh` value on `min-width`:*

```css
html,
body,
section {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

section {
  display: flex;
}

section:before,
section::after {
  content: "";
  flex: 1;/* this should be enough */
  background: antiquewhite;
  height: 100%;
}

div {
  /* flex value unnecessary i think */
  display: flex;
  height: 50%;
  background: green;
  margin: auto 0 0;/* can be used instead align-self */
}

svg {
  height: 100%;
  min-width:0.1vh;/* hack to force reflow */
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="c">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 1000 2000" class="avatar">
      <ellipse cx="500" cy="1000" rx="500" ry="1000" fill="red" />
    </svg>
  </div>
</section>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7xpoccg6/12/

`<edit>`No idea if that is a known bug and if documented anywhere,

anyone,fill free to improve this answer

**Notice, vh units is recalculated when window(or framed window) is resized vertically, works with the snippet/fiddle.**

Comment: Not sure, if it works when element is inserted dynamically, but very good point!

Comment: Adding a min-width seems to re-calculate the flex width for me on resizing the screen. Neat piece of info - thanks!